# Twitter Bootstrap Table Column - 1st Table Shorter Column Widths than 2nd Table

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, haml

I am trying to use .haml with Twitter Bootstrap to create two tables. The issue is that my 2nd table renders nicely, but my first table, which has much less text, appears to stretch endlessly across the page. How can I set my first table column width to be small, at a different width than the second table? I tried :class => "table table-condensed" but that was still too large.

```
%html
  %head
    %link(rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css")
    %link(rel="stylesheet" href="css/my.css")
    %title Working Units
  %body
    %p  
    %p These are the units that are updating. 
%table{:class => "table table-bordered"}
  %thead
    %tr 
      %th Job 
      %th Age 
  %tbody
    - @plines.each do |row|
      %tr 
        - row.split(/[-,]/).each do |column|
          %td= column
%p These are the units that are not updating. 
%table{:class => "table table-bordered"}
  %thead
    %tr 
      %th Job 
      %th Age 
      %th Time
  %tbody
    - @mlines.each do |row|
      %tr 
        - row.split(/[-,]/).each do |column|
          %td= column
%a{:href=>"/"} Back to the form
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the table in a `div` with a particular width:

```
:css
    .halfsize {
          width: 50%;
    }
.halfsize
    %table{:class => "table table-bordered"}
      %thead
        %tr 
          %th Job 
          %th Age 
      %tbody
        - @plines.each do |row|
          %tr 
            - row.split(/[-,]/).each do |column|
              %td= column
```